# MPI Cartesian Topology without 1 of the processes

Tags: c, mpi

I need to make a matrix multiplication algorithm based on Cartesian Topology. 1 of the processes should be a master process, which checks the result. What can I use to remove him from the virtual topology?

The problem comes from using the MPI_Cart_shift function.

```
void self_checking(int N, int num_procs)
{
    MPI_Status status;
    int rank;
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);

    MPI_Group world_group;
    MPI_Comm_group(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_group);
 
    int *ranks = (int *)malloc((num_procs - 1) * sizeof(int));
    for(int i = 0; i < num_procs - 1; i++)
    {
        ranks[i] = i;
    }
    MPI_Group new_group;
    MPI_Group_incl(world_group, num_procs - 1, ranks, &new_group);
 
    MPI_Comm old_comm_2d, comm_2d;
    MPI_Comm_create(MPI_COMM_WORLD, new_group, &old_comm_2d);

    int *dims = (int *)malloc(2 * sizeof(int));
    int *periods = (int *)malloc(2 * sizeof(int));
    dims[0] = dims[1] = sqrt(num_procs - 1);
    periods[0] = periods[1] = 1;
    MPI_Cart_create(old_comm_2d, 2, dims, periods, 1, &comm_2d);

    if(rank == num_procs - 1)
    {
        printf("My rank is %d\n", rank);
    }
    else
    {
        int *coords = (int *)malloc(2 * sizeof(int));
        MPI_Comm_rank(comm_2d, &rank);
        MPI_Cart_coords(comm_2d, rank, 2, coords);

        srand((unsigned int)time(NULL) + rank);

        int leftrank, rightrank, uprank, downrank;
        MPI_Cart_shift(comm_2d, 0, -1, &downrank, &uprank);
        MPI_Cart_shift(comm_2d, 1, -1, &rightrank, &leftrank);

        printf("My rank is %d, left %d, right %d, up %d, down %d\n", rank, leftrank, rightrank, uprank, downrank);
    }
}
```

Here I need to have p^2+1 processes, where 1 of them is a master process, which will multiply 2 matrices together to check if other processes did it correctly. But here MPI_Cart_shift gives an error, because it has by 1 more process.

Comment: Why don't you share your code and describe your issue?

Comment: Edited my question @GillesGouaillardet

Comment: split your `p^2+1` processes into two communicators, one with the master process, and then the other with the `p^2` processes, then create the cartesian communicator on the sub-communicator with the workers.

Comment: how do i do that if my MPI_Cart_create doesn't ask for amount of processes? @GillesGouaillardet

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question. Use the sub communicator with `p^2` processes instead of `MPI_COMM_WORLD` in `MPI_Create(...)`

Comment: I do I create a subcommunicator? I tried to create a group and use it, but I failed. I updated the code.

Comment: the easiest way is to use `MPI_Comm_split()`

Answer (score 1):

If you ask `MPI_Cart_create` to make a 4x3 grid, and you give it 13 processes, then one process will have a resulting `MPI_COMM_NULL`. You can use that one as the manager process. No need to `MPI_Comm_split` first.